# Problem with material in imported models download from website

Tags: import

When I download a free model from any 3d model website, and import it in Blender, it always shows up like this, you can see it does have diffuse and ao and other textures, but still it appears black like this, this is not the issue realated uv, because in uv it doesnt show texture like this.

I tried everything but it just doesn't seems to be solved.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hard to say, maybe overlapping face? Have you checked the UVs in the UV Editor? if it's copyright free could you please share the file?

Comment: okay, how can i share it with you. here's the link of the model [link](http://https://www.cgtrader.com/items/4536220/download-page)

Comment: the link doesn't work, use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use another platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: okay, https://workupload.com/file/CPAN8V98rng  here's the link.

Comment: it works right away on my side

Comment: can you share screen shots

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ot7RVRt.png

Comment: which version are you using of blender

Comment: 4.0.2. I notice your screenshot doesn't have the same shader. The "Skin Head Shader" was duplicated and plugged in its original's metallic map, it doesn't make any sense. https://i.stack.imgur.com/87Bye.jpg

Comment: which format is the model you downloaded and how did you import it?

Comment: the one i gave you, blender file

Comment: you don't have colored node noodles so I guess you use quite an old Blender like 2.93? That might be a reason why it's not working.

Comment: thak you so much bro, it worked in latest version, can i do something for you?

Comment: Nothing much, I added the solution as answer for visibility, glad you could find out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to update to the latest Blender version. User seemed to be using +2 years old Blender.